# php:create report

Tags: php

I want to create report using php.
This is file :
Some text, 10/07/2010  04:32
Some text, 10/07/2010  04:32
Some text, 12/07/2010  04:32
Some text, 13/07/2010  04:32

Through UI we are entering Start and end date. I have to create report based on that date.
How can i do that

Answer (score 1):

1. Get line from file.
2. Get date representation using substr and strlen.
3. Convert date to UNIX time format using strtotime.
4. Convert entered date to UNIX time format.
5. Compare two dates using simple `<` and `>` conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to build an HTML form with some date fields, either 3 dropdowns or use something like a jQueryUI datepicker.

Don't forget to validate your input!

Then when that's posted, you can create an sql `WHERE` clause from it. Then you can connect to your database and pull out the data.

Then you have a choice of just looping the data and outputting the list to the screen, and having the user save it as a CSV. Or you can buffer the output using something like `ob_start()` outputting your data, then assigning it to a variable using `ob_get_flush()` and then ouputting some CSV headers using `header()` and passing it out as a file.

Have a google around, there are lots of tutorials for creating CSV files.